# How to center php echoed element? Not working solution for now

Tags: php, html

I'm getting crazy with this code, I've tried more or less everything but nothing works for now. I already read all of your answers on others post.
The element that I need to center is a text coming from this code:

```
<?php echo htmlspecialchars($this->params->get('slide_text1')); ?>
```

The text is the "slide_text1

I hope for a quick answer because I really need to solve this problem
Thanks in advance

Comment: Please share your HTML code...

Comment: Do you know what CSS is? `text-align: center` would do the trick...

Comment: Why do you believe that this would be solved in PHP?

Answer (score 0):

How about using the CSS `text-align` attribute:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <body style="text-align: center">
  <?php
   echo htmlspecialchars($this->params->get('slide_text1'));
   ?>
 </body>
</html>
```

Aside from the PHP part (server-side), when working client-side, you have to take on account the UI dimension: CSS, HTML, JavaScript...

Comment: Please don't recommend `<center>`. It's 2013 ;)

Answer (score 0):

You just need to wrap it in a `<div>` element, and set `text-align` to `center` either in your CSS, or using the `style` attribute.

For example:

```
<?php echo '<div style="text-align: center">'.htmlspecialchars($this->params->get('slide_text1')).'</div>'; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<?php echo "<center>" . htmlspecialchars($this->params->get('slide_text1')) . "</center>"; ?>
```

Comment: As I said earlier, don't recommend `<center>`.